# SmartPointer in C++ using template

Tags: c++, templates, reference, move

I am trying to implement a smart pointer (basically unique pointer) in C++ using templates for my understanding.

This is what I have coded

```
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class smartPointer
{
    private:
        T *mPtr;
    public:
        smartPointer(T* init=nullptr):mPtr(init)
        {
            cout<<"Inside ctr"<<endl;
        }


        //silence the default ctr
        smartPointer() = delete;

        //disable copy ctr and copy assignment
        smartPointer  (const smartPointer& other) = delete;
        smartPointer& operator=(const smartPointer& other) = delete;

        //implement move ctr and move assignment
        smartPointer  (smartPointer&& other)
        {
            cout<<"Inside move ctr "<<endl;
            mPtr = other.mPtr;
            other.mPtr = nullptr;
        }
        smartPointer& operator=(smartPointer&& other)
        {

            cout<<"Inside move = before "<<endl;
            if(&other != this)
            {
                mPtr = other.mPtr;
                other.mPtr = nullptr;

                cout<<"Inside move = after "<<endl;
            }
        return *this;
        }

        //deference
        T& operator*()
        {
            return *mPtr;
        }

        //arrow  access operator
        T* operator->()
        {   
            return mPtr;
        }

        ~smartPointer()
        {   
            cout<<"Inside ~dtr"<<endl;
            if(mPtr != nullptr)
            delete mPtr;
        }

};



int main()
{

     smartPointer<int> sptr(new int);

     // Even smartPointer<int> sptr(new int[20]); too works

     *sptr = 10;
     cout<<"Value pointed by the pointer  is "<<*sptr<<endl;     

    smartPointer<int> sptr2(new int);

//  sptr2 = sptr; // complains as expected
    sptr2 = move(sptr); // works well

    /*
    How to 

    smartPointer<int[]>  sptr(new int[20]); 
    */

    return 0;
}
```

How to make this smart pointer to work for smartPointer ?

The build command I give is 
g++ -std=c++11 -smartPointer.cpp -o smartPointer

Comment: Please [remove the `using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1):

You can add `operator[]` to the base template, and use SFINAE to ensure it only compiles when the type is an array type. You would do the same to make sure `operaotr*` and `operaotr->` only compile for the non-array version. Then, tag dispatch can be used to call the correct `delete` expression.

```
template<typename T>
class smartPointer
{
    private:
        T *mPtr;

        del_member(std::true_type) { delete[] mPtr; }
        del_member(std::false_type) { delete mPtr; }

    public:
        // Removed you code for brevity.

        //deference
        auto operator*() -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_array<T>::value, T&>
        {
            return *mPtr;
        }

        //arrow  access operator
        auto operator->() -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_array<T>::value, T*>
        {   
            return mPtr;
        }

        auto operator[](std::size_t idx) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_array<T>::value, T&>
        {   
            return mPtr[idx];
        }

        ~smartPointer()
        {   
            del_member(std::is_array<T>{});
        }
};
```

The above is perfectly legal, and can exist in the same template. Remember the members of a template are instantiated only when used. So unless users of your class *try to use* an operator which the underlying pointer shouldn't support, they will get no errors.

---

If your compiler doesn't support c++14 type traits yet, the above trailing return types can be turned to the form:

```
typename std::enable_if<CONDITION, TYPE>::type
```

---

For your c'tor, I recommend you don't hard-code `T*`. Instead add the following type alias to your class, and change the c'tor accordingly.

```
using ptr_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_array<T>::value, std::decayt_t<T>, std::add_pointer_t<T>>;

smartPointer(ptr_type init)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am accepting your answer. thank you :) Learnt a new thing SIFNAE and thank you  for very quick reply:)

Comment: can you help me in the constructor, I get this error

 error: no matching function for call to ‘smartPointer<int []>::smartPointer(int*)’
      smartPointer<int[]> sptr(new int[20]);

Comment: @balu - See my edit. Buf if you have more problems, post another question. SO is not a forum.

Comment: conditional_t is not available in c++ 11.

Comment: @balu what I wrote about `enable_if` applies as well to `conditional_t`